# Same listview item added everytime the application runs

Tags: android, android-listview

I have trying to retrieve data from database(set of contacts) on a web-server and trying to show the data using ListViews. Whenever i run my application, each time it adds the same list item into the list. The image will explain it better:

[image]

This is the first time I run my application(After I install it). Now i exit my application and run it again. The result is:[image]

Here is the code of my application:

```
RegisterMe reg=connect.new RegisterMe(); //RegisterMe is an asynchronous task used
    reg.execute(myPhoneNumber); // to receive data. execute() fxn is called 
                                // which invokes doInBackground() fxn.
    /*try{
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } */


      adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,mutualFriends,R.layout.activity_first,new String[]{KEY_NAME,KEY_NUMBER}
                                ,new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Code for doInBackground() is as follows:

```
protected class RegisterMe extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
protected String doInBackground(String... str)
{
        String myPhoneNumber;
        myPhoneNumber=str[0];
        InputStream is = null;
        String result=new String();
        HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://johnconnor.comuf.com/register.php");
        try
        {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mynumber",myPhoneNumber));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response= httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.i("postData",response.getStatusLine().toString());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
           }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } 

        result=result.substring(0,result.indexOf('\n'));
        return result ;  //result contains "Neeraj,"123456789"
}
```

Code for onPostExecute is as follows:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{

    String[] array;
    array=result.split("[/]");

    HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++)
    {
        String[] singleContact;
        singleContact=array[i].split("[,]");
        map.put(FirstActivity.KEY_NAME,singleContact[0]);
        map.put(FirstActivity.KEY_NUMBER, singleContact[1]);
        FirstActivity.mutualFriends.add(map);
    }
    FirstActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I have checked using debugger that result only contains "Neeraj,123456789". But everytime i run my application, the same listview item gets added. All i want is to display it only once. Can anyone here please??

Thanks,

Comment: If `mutualFriends` is a static variable, it can be maintained longer that you'd wanted. You need to clean that list before launcher you async task.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that it's due to

```
FirstActivity.mutualFriends.add(map);
```

You're adding a new entry using this. So the first time you'd start the application, there is only one entry. Second time you start, there's two.

Assuming the `mutualFriends` you're using is an Arraylist. Try adding

```
FirstActivity.mutualFriends.clear();
```

before adding a new record.

Answer (score 0):

The one solution is make sure your array is being clear 
or

always make null arraylist before adding data

or 
last end ever used for big data is store your data in to sqlite and get data from that
before adding data in sqlite , delete all records from db and fill again so it will not show you duplicate data.